# rich:jQuery not working in IE8

Tags: java, jquery, richfaces

I want to trigger a new click event (on the same button) after a button from a modal panel was clicked. Something like click to simulate double click on that button.

I used this code:

```
<a4j:form>
...
<rich:jQuery name="testClick" selector="#myButton" timing="onJScall" query="trigger('click');" />
<a4j:commandButton id="myButton" ... onclick="testClick();" ...  oncomplete="#{rich:component('myModalPanel')}.hide();" ... /> ...
```

On Firefox this code is working so, if i click on "myButton" than another click event is triggered, but in IE this is not happing, please if you have an idea how to solve this, give me a hand...

Thanks,

Radu

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have JavaScript activated in IE8. Also, Try activating the **compatibility** mode on IE8 and see what happen.

The problem might now be JQuery itself, since it is guaranteed to work across all major browsers, but the way that Richfaces actually uses it. Do these checks and lets see if we can further analyze the problem.

Regards.